# Authorize.net : An error occurred on the server Please try to place order again

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have configured Authorize.Net Payment method in Magento 2.1.7, In checkout page, I'm using credit card transaction both production and test mode while placing the order, I am getting "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again".

Activating debug mode I didn't get any log files. Please Let me know it is a Magento issue or payment gateway issue.

Comment: can you please check if in magento log settings are enabled or not. ?

Comment: please check consol or magento log file and try to resolve that error.

Comment: in log file only showing cache invalidate issue. it's not related to payment gateway issues.

Comment: Please make sure able to place an order without authorize.net

Comment: Cash on delivery and Paypal gateway working properly. In authorize.net order will be placed in the backend without transaction id and status is pending.

Answer (score 0):

For Sandbox mode,please check your configuration as following settings are working fine for me @Magento2.2.4:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer above settings are fine in my Magento. We discuss with Authorize.net support team They said Magento didn't send the transaction payment request to Authorize.net gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support guys, finally found the issue. The patch update file **Request.php** in authorize.net is not working properly.
Line no.209

```
private function getSignatureKey(): string
  {
    return $this->signatureKey;
  }
```

and **Response.php** Line No. 109

```
 foreach ($hashFields as $field) {
            $message .= ($this->getData($field) ?? '') . '^';
        }
```

The above types of representations is not working in Magento 2.1.7 with PHP 5.6.

We tested in new Magento instance with PHP 7.0.2 Authorize.net working properly without any transaction error.